# Difference between presenceOfElementLocated() and presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy() is Selenium

Tags: selenium

From the [Documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) I see that
`presenceOfElementLocated​(By locator)` is "An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page" while
`presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy​(By locator)` is "An expectation for checking that there is at least one element present on a web page"
So what is the actual difference between these 2 methods?

Comment: One main difference is the first returns webelement second returns list of webelements

Comment: OK. But still `presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy​(By locator)` will not wait for the presence of all the elements located by the passed locator on the page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/bf2fc564eeaeecfd980984119bd18d0a00bdb29e/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.java

Its an interesting question and there is no much difference than that , if you check the source code the first returns an webelement second returns an webelement array/list.

**Thats the only thing it does. IT doesn't wait for all elements it returns true as soon as elements.size>0**

**Update:**

if anyone is wondering why presenceofelement work in case of element not found:

**if you check  webdriver wait code , you can see that there is an ignoreexception for elementnotfound**

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/0f197cbd4fa9acdd2ac3ddebbe0cc9b4ca26bff8/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.java

so the code waits till element is found and ignores elementnotfound during the poll time

Comment: I see, so `presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy​(By locator)` will not actually wait for the presence of all the elements located by the passed locator on the page

Comment: That's correct  it just returns non empty webelement array

Answer (score 1):

### presenceOfElementLocated​()

As per the documentation, [presenceOfElementLocated​()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#presenceOfElementLocated(org.openqa.selenium.By)) is the expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page and returns the WebElement once it is located. This does not garuntees that the element is visible.

As per the [source code](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/bf2fc564eeaeecfd980984119bd18d0a00bdb29e/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.java#L163):

```
    /**
     * An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page. This does not
     * necessarily mean that the element is visible.
     *
     * @param locator used to find the element
     * @return the WebElement once it is located
     */
    public static ExpectedCondition<WebElement> presenceOfElementLocated(final By locator) {
      return new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>() {
        @Override
        public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
          return driver.findElement(locator);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
          return "presence of element located by: " + locator;
        }
      };
    }
```

---

### presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy()

As per the documentation, [presenceOfElementLocated​()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#presenceOfElementLocated(org.openqa.selenium.By)) is the  expectation for checking that there is at least one element present on a web page and returns the list of WebElements once they are located.

As per the [source code](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/bf2fc564eeaeecfd980984119bd18d0a00bdb29e/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.java#L310):

```
    /**
     * An expectation for checking that there is at least one element present on a web page.
     *
     * @param locator used to find the element
     * @return the list of WebElements once they are located
     */
    public static ExpectedCondition<List<WebElement>> presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(
      final By locator) {
      return new ExpectedCondition<List<WebElement>>() {
        @Override
        public List<WebElement> apply(WebDriver driver) {
          List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(locator);
          return elements.size() > 0 ? elements : null;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
          return "presence of any elements located by " + locator;
        }
      };
    }
```

---

### This usecase

The major difference between them is, `presenceOfElementLocated()` would return the WebElement as soon as it is located while `presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy()` would keep on collecting the present elements till the *`TimeOut`* is reached or the search reaches to the bottom of the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) and would return the list of WebElements.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you are wrong. First of all here I asked about the difference between `presenceOfElementLocated` vs `presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy`. Both methods are checking element(s) presence only, we are not talking about their visibility at all.

Comment: `presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy` will NOT keep on collecting the elements until the `TimeOut`. It will return almost immediately after finding the first match. It will even not search to the bottom of the DOM. we have tested this method behavior on multiple sites where some kind of list is being loaded. The method will normally return 4, maybe 3 or 5 elements in case of total match of let's say 200 visible elements in the list. But, again, it will return the result of matching list shortly after finding the first match.

Comment: When you are asking about presence of element(s), there is a necessity to keep the broader audience updated the either of `presenceOfElementLocated` or `presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy` does not garuntees that the element(s) are visible/hidden. How much deeper you want to understand would be as per your appetiate.

Comment: As I understand it works as following: Selenium is polling the DOM every X milliseconds. So, once there is a polling with at lest 1 match it will take all the current matches and retuirn this list.

Comment: Well, again, I asked about the difference between these 2 methods. I do not need to describe to all the beginners here that presence will not guarantee element visibility. I also do not need to describe here about stale element and the rest of nuances we should consider when using Selenium to deal with Web Elements....
But I really appreciate you answers Debanjan