# Not able to click on link in <li> elements list python code

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

Please Help!!
I want to click on all main menu links for this i have written following code:

```
 html_list = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='main-navigation']/ul")
 items = html_list.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
        for item in items:
            item.click()
            time.sleep(20)
```

but it clicked on first menu option **Brands** and then it failed and gave following error:

```
   exception_class = ErrorInResponseException
        if status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_ELEMENT:
            exception_class = NoSuchElementException
        elif status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_FRAME:
            exception_class = NoSuchFrameException
        elif status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_WINDOW:
            exception_class = NoSuchWindowException
        elif status in ErrorCode.STALE_ELEMENT_REFERENCE:
            exception_class = StaleElementReferenceException
        elif status in ErrorCode.ELEMENT_NOT_VISIBLE:
            exception_class = ElementNotVisibleException
        elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_ELEMENT_STATE:
            exception_class = InvalidElementStateException
E       selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

I am attaching screenshot of the webpage on which I am performing this action.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
html_list = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id = 'main-navigation']//li[.//a[not(@data-webtrekk-link-id='header.subnav')]]")))
for i in range(len(html_list)):
    time.sleep(3)
    html_list = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id = 'main-navigation']//li[.//a[not(@data-webtrekk-link-id='header.subnav')]]")))
    html_list[i].click()
```

there are many invisible elements , you should use the xpath locator as mentioned to find the element uniquely.

we are using time.sleep because presenceofallelement doesn't wait for all elements but for only first element

[Difference between presenceOfElementLocated() and presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy() is Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66369199/difference-between-presenceofelementlocated-and-presenceofallelementslocatedby/66369378#66369378)

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for sharing solution it detail. It worked. Thanks alot. :)

Comment: Hi, I want to understand this part "a[not(@data-webtrekk-link-id='header.subnav')]". does it mean to go to tagnamed a when attribute data-webtrekk-link-id is not 'header.subnav'

Comment: no it means select 'li' tag only if it doesn't have a child 'a' element with id as "header subnav"

Comment: could you upvote also by pressing the up arrow

Comment: last thing, as you said " select 'li' tag only if it doesn't have a child 'a' element with id as "header subnav" " but why you did not use as  a[@data-webtrekk-link-id='header.nav] ?

Comment: there where multiple elements with that attribute that is not visible in the screen

Comment: `//*[@id = 'main-navigation']//a[@data-webtrekk-link-id='header.nav']` this works

Comment: if you link to parent then it is uniquely identifies the li tags, you can use that also i didn't notice that locator

Comment: yes it is also working fine. Sure. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you click on element from items, it changes in DOM making it impossible to continue to iterate through items because of StaleElementReference. Inspect elements to see how the structure changes.

I would suggest iterating by index instead of elements

```
html_list = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='main-navigation']/ul")
items = html_list.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
for i, _j in enumerate(items, start=1):
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//*[@id='main-navigation']/ul/li)[{}]".format(i))
    time.sleep(20)
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for this solution, it worked :)