# Selenium python: get all the <li> text of all the <ul> from a <div>

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, html-parsing

I would like to get all the list of word that are as `dutch word = english word`  from several pages.

By examining the HTML, it means that I need to get all the texts from all the `li` of all the `ul` from the child div of `#mw-content-text`.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')  # start chrome without opening window
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

listURL = [
    "https://duolingo.fandom.com/wiki/Dutch_(NL)_Skill:Basics_1",
    "https://duolingo.fandom.com/wiki/Dutch_(NL)_Skill:Basics_2",
    "https://duolingo.fandom.com/wiki/Dutch_(NL)_Skill:Phrases_1",
    "https://duolingo.fandom.com/wiki/Dutch_(NL)_Skill:Negative_1",
]


list_text = []
for url in listURL:
    driver.get(url)
    elem = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/ul')
    for each_ul in elem:
        all_li = each_ul.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
        for li in all_li:
            list_text.append(li.text)

print(list_text)
```

Here is the output

```
['man = man', 'vrouw = woman', 'jongen = boy', 'ik = I', 'ben = am', 'een = a/an', 'en = and', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

I don't understand why some `li` text are not retrieve even though their xpath is the same (I double check several of them via the copy xpath of the developer console)

Comment: What is `li` on the page?

Comment: @vitaliis, thanks for you time. sorry for this mistake, I have edited the question to make is clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try waiting for the page to fully load before parsing it, one way is to use the [`time.sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep) method:

```
from time import sleep
...

for url in listURL:
    driver.get(url)
    sleep(5)
    ...
```

---

EDIT: Using `BeautifulSoup`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


listURL = [
    "https://duolingo.fandom.com/wiki/Dutch_(NL)_Skill:Basics_1",
    "https://duolingo.fandom.com/wiki/Dutch_(NL)_Skill:Basics_2",
    "https://duolingo.fandom.com/wiki/Dutch_(NL)_Skill:Phrases_1",
    "https://duolingo.fandom.com/wiki/Dutch_(NL)_Skill:Negative_1",
]


list_text = []
for url in listURL:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
    print("Link:", url)
    
    for tag in soup.select("[id*=Lesson]:not([id*=Lessons])"):
        print(tag.text)
        print()
        print(tag.find_next("ul").text)
        print("-" * 80)
    print()
```

Output (truncated):

```
Link: https://duolingo.fandom.com/wiki/Dutch_(NL)_Skill:Basics_1
Lesson 1

man = man
vrouw = woman
jongen = boy
ik = I
ben = am
een = a/an
en = and
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Lesson 2

meisje = girl
kind = child/kid
hij = he
ze = she (unstressed)
is = is
of = or
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Lesson 3

appel = apple

... And on
```

If you want the output as a `list`:

```
for url in listURL:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
    print("Link:", url)
    print([tag.text for tag in soup.select(".mw-parser-output > ul li")])
    print("-" * 80)
```

Comment: thanks for this but something is really weird : when I add the sleep, that I don't have any word in the output even though I only added the `sleep(5)` and not changed the xpath or anything else  (if I comment out the sleep, the few words from the question are back).

Comment: Maybe the page is stuck on loading. try printing anything after the `sleep`,does that output?

Comment: @vitaliis Why? when running the OP's code on my machine I do get an output, shouldn't the problem be a need to wait for elements to load?

Comment: @MendelG, I tried `print("test")` and `print(driver)`` and both are printed

Comment: @MendelG, you wrote that you ` get an output`. Do you get the full output of all the words from all the pages?

Comment: Yes, it works. I overreacted. Sorry. But he'll save some time if he will be using explicit or implicit wait from `selenium.webdriver.support.wait` library.

Comment: @vitaliis Correct, I know that solution which is much better. That's why I wrote: "_**one way**  is to use the time.sleep() method_"

Comment: Ok, I also use it for debugging, but I do not push it.

Comment: For many pages 5 seconds load time would be not enough

Comment: @vitaliis I know your answer is much more efficient, I'll delete my and upvote yours.

Comment: No, not need to delete it. It also answers question

Comment: @MagTun Try adding more time to `sleep()`

Comment: @vitaliis and MendelG, I tried a sleep of 30 secs, btu still nothing. On my "normal" browser, the page load in a couple of second

Comment: @MagTun Would you like to use BeautifulSoup as an alternative to scrape the page?

Comment: I'd also be interested to see it.

Comment: sorry for the delay MendelG, and thanks so much because it's working with beautifulsoup though it's really weird because the parsing is similar to the on in the selenium code `.mw-parser-output > ul li`. I don't understand what is happening with selenium!

Answer (score 1):

Your script seems to be ok, but I'd add explicit or implicit wait.
Try to wait till all elements on a page are visible:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')  # start chrome without opening window

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver', options=options)
listURL = [
    "https://duolingo.fandom.com/wiki/Dutch_(NL)_Skill:Basics_1",
    "https://duolingo.fandom.com/wiki/Dutch_(NL)_Skill:Basics_2",
    "https://duolingo.fandom.com/wiki/Dutch_(NL)_Skill:Phrases_1",
    "https://duolingo.fandom.com/wiki/Dutch_(NL)_Skill:Negative_1",
]


list_text = []
for url in listURL:
    driver.get(url)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/ul')))
    elem = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/ul')
    for each_ul in elem:
        all_li = each_ul.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
        for li in all_li:
            list_text.append(li.text)

print(list_text)
```

Also, you can add `driver.implicitly_wait(15)` right after you declare `driver`.

Output:

```
['man = man', 'vrouw = woman', 'jongen = boy', 'ik = I', 'ben = am', 'een = a/an', 'en = and', 'meisje = girl', 'kind = child/kid', 'hij = he', 'ze = she (unstressed)', 'is = is', 'of = or', 'appel = apple', 'melk = milk', 'drinkt = drinks (2nd and 3rd person singular)', 'drink = drink (1st person singular)', 'eet = eat(s) (singular)', 'de = the', 'sap = juice', 'water = water', 'brood = bread', 'het = it, the', 'je = you (singular informal, unstressed)', 'bent = are (2nd person singular)', 'Zijn (to be)', 'Hebben (to have)', 'Mogen (to be allowed to)', 'Willen (to want)', 'Kunnen (to be able to)', 'Zullen ("will")', 'boterham = sandwich', 'rijst = rice', 'we = we (unstressed)', 'jullie = you (plural informal)', 'eten = eat (plural)', 'drinken = drink (plural)', 'vrouwen = women', 'mannen = men', 'meisjes = girls', 'krant = newspaper', 'lezen = read (plural)', 'jongens = boys', 'menu = menu', 'dat = that', 'zijn = are (plural)', 'ze = they (unstressed)', 'heb = have (1st person singular)', 'heeft = has (3rd person singular)', 'hebt = have (2nd person singular)', 'hebben = have (plural)', 'boek = book', 'lees = read (1st person singular)', 'leest = read(s) (2nd and 3rd person singular)', 'kinderen = children', 'spreken = speak (plural)', 'spreek = speak (1st person singular)', 'spreekt = speak(s) (2nd and 3rd person singular)', 'hallo = hello', 'bedankt = thanks', 'doei = bye', 'dag = goodbye', 'tot ziens = see you later', 'hoi = hi', 'goedemorgen = good morning', 'goededag = good day', 'goedenavond = good evening', 'goedenacht = good night', 'welterusten = good night', 'ja = yes', 'dank je wel = thank you very much', 'alsjeblieft = please', 'sorry = sorry', 'het spijt me = I am sorry', 'oké = okay', 'pardon = excuse me', 'hoe gaat het = how are you', 'goed = good, fine, well', 'dank je = thank you', '(een) beetje = (a) bit of', 'Engels = English', 'Nederlands = Dutch', 'Geen: negating indefinite nouns (you can think of it as "no" things or "none of" a thing if that helps). Geen replaces the indefinite pronoun in question.', 'Niet: negating a verb, adjective or definite nouns. Niet comes at the end of a sentence or directly after the verb zijn.', 'nee = no', 'niet = not', 'geen = not']
```

**Update:**
I found a more reliable way with CSS selectors. Try it please:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')  # start chrome without opening window

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver', options=options)
driver.implicitly_wait(15)
listURL = [
    "https://duolingo.fandom.com/wiki/Dutch_(NL)_Skill:Basics_1",
    "https://duolingo.fandom.com/wiki/Dutch_(NL)_Skill:Basics_2",
    "https://duolingo.fandom.com/wiki/Dutch_(NL)_Skill:Phrases_1",
    "https://duolingo.fandom.com/wiki/Dutch_(NL)_Skill:Negative_1",
]


list_text = []
for url in listURL:
    driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[id*='google_ads_iframe'] ")))
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.mw-parser-output>ul')))
    elem = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.mw-parser-output>ul')
    for each_ul in elem:
        all_li = each_ul.find_elements_by_css_selector("li")
        for li in all_li:
            list_text.append(li.text)

print(list_text)
```

**Update 2**
After trying to understand the reason I found out that ads take the most of the time of loading. So I'm adding `wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[id*='google_ads_iframe'] ")))` that waits till all ads are loaded.

I also changed the second wait to `.mw-parser-output>ul` by removing last `li`. I think it is not necessary. You can also try removing the second wait and see if it helps.

Comment: I get this error `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:`

Comment: What is the message?

Comment: the message is empty

Comment: Try using `presence_of_all_elements_located` and make timeout not 5 but 10 or 15 seconds

Comment: `presence_of_all_elements_located` is sort of working: no error but the output is still buggy: `['man = man', 'vrouw = woman', 'jongen = boy', 'ik = I', 'ben = am', 'een = a/an', 'en = and', 'meisje = girl', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'Zijn (to be)', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'hallo = hello', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']`

Comment: I always get the result, try the same without headless mode. Maybe the issue is because of it

Comment: It's getting better: I am getting all the words from the first and the second page but I am missing all the ones from the third and fourth page

Comment: @vitaliis I wasn't able to ping you on my answer, I have added a solution using BeautifulSoup

Comment: @MendelG Thanks!

Comment: @MagTun Check updated answer with css selectors. I found out that using tag names is not very reliable.

Comment: After updating my answer, I noticed the output is not in `list`,  I basically used the same CSS Selector as you (without noticing you answer)

Comment: Yes, looks like locators were the main problem

Comment: sorry for the delay, I tried the solution with `find_elements_by_css_selector` but I am getting the same error with an empty message `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:`. The solution from @MendelG with beautifulsoup is working though it is based on the same selection `.mw-parser-output > ul li`. It's really weird, I don't understand why it's sort of working with selenium but not fully.

Comment: Check updated answer that waits for ads to load. It looks like the page is loaded, but afterwards, the ads are also dynamically loaded and elements on the page are shifting. Also, please upvote if the answer was at least helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the time you are spending on debugging this. I tried you last edit and I am still getting the same error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 24, in <module>
    (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[id*='google_ads_iframe'] ")))
  File "C:\Users\u\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:` with an empty message

Answer (score 0):

After

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/ul')))
```

you need to add some sleep, I guess `time.sleep(1)` will be enough and only after that do

```
elem = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/ul')
```

Your problem is caused by misunderstanding `visibility_of_all_elements_located` functionality.
It is not actually waiting for all the elements located by the locator you passing it to become visible, it has no idea for what amount of such elements to wait.
So once it detects at least 1 element matching your locator visible - it returns the list of detected elements and the program continues forward.
See more details about those methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66369199/difference-between-presenceofelementlocated-and-presenceofallelementslocatedby) and in the official documentation.

Comment: From source code: `An expectation for checking that all elements are present on the DOM of a
    page and visible. Visibility means that the elements are not only displayed
    but also has a height and width that is greater than 0.
    locator - used to find the elements
    returns the list of WebElements once they are located and visible`

Comment: Did you see the link and the answer there? How do you think Selenium should know for what amount of elements to wait?

Comment: Yes, I checked it. I agree with it. As for me this question needs more exploration. To understand it better `_find_elements` inner method should also be taken into account.

Comment: I am getting the same error than with @vitaliis answer `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:` and the message is empty. But I see that the page is fully loaded (including the words I want to retrieve) in the browser open by selenium.

Comment: On what code line are you getting this error?

Comment: @Prophet, I am getting it on the line `WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(
        (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/ul')))` . Here is the last lines of the debug  : 

`Traceback (most recent call last):  File ".", line 22, in <module> 
    (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/ul')))
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:`

Comment: AFAIK this means there are no elements with locator you provided on the page. Also, I see no such expected condition for python in documentation https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html