# Selenium - element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I'm trying to scrape a webpage, getting links from main pages and then scrape every page individually. This error occurs sometimes, but not always. I've tried to use WebDriverWait and scroll to end of page, but sometimes I still get this error

How can I asure selenium will only click the button after is loaded?

init.py

```
import scraper

urls_globo = [
    # 'https://g1.globo.com/brasil', #TODO PAGINA INICIAL, MANTER?
    'https://g1.globo.com/ciencia', 
    'https://g1.globo.com/mundo',   
    'https://g1.globo.com/politica',
    'https://g1.globo.com/saude',   
    'https://g1.globo.com/tecnologia'
]

for url in urls_globo:
    print('\nCATEGORIA: ' + url.split('/')[-1])
    navegador = scraper.GetPages(url)
    links = scraper.GetLinksFromPage(navegador, 20)
    for link in links:
        print(link)
```

scraper.py

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

opcoes = Options()
opcoes.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
opcoes.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
# opcoes.headless = True

#desabiltando anuncios = instalar bloqueador do navegador

navegador = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/julia/repos/pos/novo/chromedriver.exe', options=opcoes)
# espera = WebDriverWait(navegador, 10)

def GetPages(url):
    try:
        navegador.get(url)
    except Exception as e:
        raise SystemExit(e)
    
    return navegador

def GetLinksFromPage(navegador, itens_meta):

    espera = WebDriverWait(navegador, 20)
    
    links = []
    #itens_meta = 15


    while itens_meta > len(links):

        #1 - desce a página até o botão aparecer pela 1a vez
        navegador.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

        #3 - Clique no botão para mais conteudo
        espera.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'load-more'))).click()


        #2 - pega todos links de todos os elementos carregados
        espera.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'feed-post-body')))
        #elementos = navegador.find_elements(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='feed-post-link')
        elementos = espera.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'feed-post-link')))
        temp_links = []
        temp_links = [elem.get_attribute('href') for elem in elementos]
        # links.append(temp_links)

        #4 - atualiza a lista que controla o loop
        links.append(temp_links)    

    # print(links)
    # print(len(links))
    #navegador.quit()
    return links
```

stacktrace

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That page can be scraped without the overheads and complexities of Selenium: you can use requests/bs4 instead:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers= {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)
for x in range(1, 10): ## pick up the range here
    r = s.get(f'https://g1.globo.com/ciencia/index/feed/pagina-{x}.ghtml', headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    news = soup.select('div.feed-post-body')
    for n in news:
        title = n.select_one('a')
        print(title.get_text(strip=True))
```

This returns the titles, but you can select any other elements:

```
O supertelescópio que vai investigar a origem das estrelas
Pesquisa liga beijos na Idade do Bronze a origem da herpes labial
Os animais que fazem arte - e podem ter vantagens evolutivas com isso
O que é a hipótese de Gaia, que defende que a Terra 'está viva'
Septuagenárias e rebeldes
```

If you are keen on using Selenium, then bear in mind that page will load the first three pages worth of news by detecting scrolling to the bottom of the page, and then you can click the button to take you to page 4. You also need to dismiss the cookie button, and to wait for the heavy javascript adverts from page to load.You also need to account for the actual url of the page changing on click, and to redefine the elements.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing the following:

1. Change the `element_to_be_clickable` with `visibility_of_element_located`.
   The second condition should wait for more mature element state. During the page rendering some element (you want to click) will be defined as clickable by Selenium while it is still not fully rendered. it still may not be on it final position or some other element may be over it on that moment. While `visibility_of_element_located` should mean that no other element over that element, it is visible (and also clickable if it intended to be so).
   Also
2. take in account that `visibility_of_all_elements_located` will NOT actually wait for visibility of all elements matching the locator passed there. this method will wait for AT LEAST ONE match i.e. for at least 1 element matching the `feed-post-link` class name in your case visibility.
   So, after `espera.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'feed-post-link')))` it would be better to add some delay, let's say of 1 second, and only after that to collect the list of `elementos`.

Comment: so how is this different from visibility_of_element_located?

Comment: i made this changes and now it throws same error at the beginning of execution

Comment: i really thought that, since i'm waiting for elements to load, i would not need sleep

Comment: As about your first question: The only difference between these 2 methods is that `visibility_of_element_located` returns a WebElement object while `visibility_of_all_elements_located` returns a list of WebElement objects

Comment: See here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66369199/difference-between-presenceofelementlocated-and-presenceofallelementslocatedby The answer is done by really very experienced person. His score is not too high, but he knows much more than me :)

Comment: Also, it is really possible that you have to close the banner before clicking the "load more" button as mentioned by Parolla.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is a footer AcceptCookies banner which intecepts the click you might need to accept the Cookies before click on LoadMore button:

```
espera.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'cookie-banner-lgpd_text'))).click()
espera.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'cookie-banner-lgpd')))
```

Answer (score -1):

The click to the desired element is getting intercepted by the ***cookie banner***.

---

### Details

Before you start scrapping the webpage clicking on the ***Load More*** element, you should accept the cookie consent so the [Viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130869/7429447) is maximum and `ElementClickInterceptedException` isn't raised while clicking on the desired elements.

---

### Solution

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.cookie-banner-lgpd_text-box"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='cookie-banner-lgpd_text-box']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> PS: Ideally `<div>` tags aren't **clickable**. So you may need to find a decendant `<button>` or a `<span>` to invoke the click.